# Dagster unable to import module

Tags: python, import, python-module, dagster

I'm new to Dagster and I'm struggling importing my module into the Dagster code.
This is my project structure.

```bash
.
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── my-project
│   ├── assets.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── assets.cpython-311.pyc
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-311.pyc
│   ├── scaled_dataset.csv
│   └── utilities
│       ├── dataset.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── nn.py
│       ├── plotting.py
│       ├── testing.py
│       └── training.py
```

In my `__init__.py` of `my-poject` I have set

```py
from dagster import Definitions, load_assets_from_modules

from . import assets, utilities

all_assets = load_assets_from_modules([assets, utilities])

defs = Definitions(
    assets=all_assets,
)
```

And in my code in `assets.py` I have (for example):

```py
from utilities.plotting import plot_dataset
```

However, when I run `dagster dev', it returns:

```bash
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities'

Stack Trace:
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Dagster/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dagster/_core/code_pointer.py", line 135, in load_python_module
    return importlib.import_module(module_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Dagster/my-project/my-project/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import assets, utilities
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/Dagster/my-project/my-project/assets.py", line 12, in <module>
    from utilities.plotting import plot_dataset
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this:

First, rename `my-project` to `my_project`.
Next, install your project as editable from the root folder:
`pip install -e .`

And then update your imports so they look like this:

`from my_project.utilities.plotting import plot_dataset`

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem. I had also to change the path inside the module.